# img srcset in vue-cli project results in compile error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I have an image for a `vue-cli` project, and it works fine with the following path:

```html
<img src="../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_2086.jpg" alt="">
```

But when I insert image URLs with [`srcset`](https://responsivebreakpoints.com/) for responsive image breakpoints, I see a compile error.

Here is the generated image code:

```html
<img sizes="(max-width: 3840px) 100vw, 3840px" 
    srcset="../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_320.jpg 
    320w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_1099.jpg 
    1099w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_1647.jpg 
    1647w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_2086.jpg 
    2086w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_2460.jpg 
    2460w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_2848.jpg 2848w, 
    ../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_3214.jpg 
    3214w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_3556.jpg 
    3556w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_3805.jpg 
    3805w,../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_3840.jpg 3840w"
    src="../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_3840.jpg" alt="">
```

#### Error!

[image: screenshot of console error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `vue-loader` does not handle commas in `srcset` filenames/URLs. It simply [splits the `srcset` string by `,`](https://github.com/vuejs/component-compiler-utils/blob/08cd399/lib/templateCompilerModules/srcset.ts#L35), so the first `srcset` value of `../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale,w_320.jpg` is parsed as `../assets/images/banner/hero_2x_w4eyw5_c_scale`, leading to the `Module not found` error in your screenshot.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) indicate that the `srcset` values are comma-delimited, and it's unclear whether the commas are permitted within the filenames/URLs. In any case, you could resolve the build errors by renaming your files to remove the commas, and updating the references in your `srcset` to match.